# TS - How to execute a string function on a type value inside a type generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this `valuesToUpperCase` generic, where I want to get a type as an input and uppercase its values and return it

I have tried this but I get an error saying `'toUppercase' implicitly has an 'any' return type`

```
type GeneralType = {
  name: string;
  car: string;
}

  type valuesToUpperCase<T extends GeneralType> = {
    name: T['firstName'].toUpperCase(),
    car: T['lastName'].toUpperCase(),
  }
```

Comment: Your GeneralType doen not have firstName so that won't work. Fix the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type GeneralType = {
  name: 'asIgbiB';
  car: 'iaygfIUGI';
}

type x = Uppercase
//        ^? type Uppercase<S extends string> = intrisic

type AllAsUppercase<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
   [K in keyof T]: Uppercase<T[K]>
}

type y = AllAsUppercase<GeneralType>
//   ^?
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBDANgFXNAvFA3gFBRTwoC2EAXFAOQoDOAkgOYBGAlgEK0DcxUAMYokNWhxQgWAMyYBVGEz6EAvoUKhIUAB5Q8csJCTCGEQgHpzJa9YB6AfiiboBoyYgAeAMpQI24AgAJgxQDMBIHPAsAHx6UJHhHAwcgurOUACCaGgZDK7I7h4Yvv5BIQBKEIIA9kiBHmERUQA0oYlR0bF4RNYA2gDS8fBQANYQINXSUBgAujT5xoyeGAMz0app2FAgcVk5eYYFSx5wiKiY2OuWdvZAA)

Comment: how would I declare Uppercase?

Comment: @Uranium_x02 you don't have to, it's built in to Typescript itself. That's what Dimava presumably meant by "intrinsic"

Comment: It's literally declared as `type Uppercase<S extends string> = intrisic`, as you may find if you hover it, meaning it's not a user-makeable type (like Record) but a compiler feature

Comment: It helps if you explain answer posts with more than just code (although you don't have to write twenty pages like I tend to do ), and provide links to sources, such as [the handbook documentation for `UpperCase<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype).

Comment: what if I wanted to reverse it instead of transforming to uppercase, what would I do?

Comment: ``type Reverse<S extends string, O extends string = ''> = S extends `${infer F}${infer L}` ? Reverse<L, `${F}${O}`> : O`` --- you would google a solution for that